# jqGrid : open a customised form on click of 'Edit' button and after edit refresh that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I need to open a customized form on click of 'Edit' button which is present on each row of jqGird. Here I know that, I have to open this form on event called 'OnEdit'. To a customized form I will pass information of selected row so that I can edit my information and then I will click on 'Save'  button present on my form.

On click of 'Save' button following things should be happened :
1. All modified data will get inserted in database.
2 Selected row should be updated with modified value.

Please tell me how I can do this. Also let me know your suggestions.

Note : I am using ASP .Net MVC website.
Thank You

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 0):

Basic points:

1) You open/close the gridview and the edit form with `Panel`
 2) You use the OnRowCommand to trigger the edit
 3) You have other buttons inside the form to trigger the save/cancel/close

and here is the basic code:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlViewList" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvMyList" OnRowCommand="RowCommand" DataKeyNames="UserId" ..........>
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Edit" CommandName="EditMe" />
            ........rest of your fields.........
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id="pnlEdit" runat="server">
    <h2>form edit</h2>
    Name : <asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server" />
    ........rest of your form.........
</asp:Panel>
```

and on code behind you capture the edit from the grid view.

```
protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditMe")
    {
        int iTheIndexNow;
        if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out iTheIndexNow))
        {
                gvMyList.SelectedIndex = iTheIndexNow;
                // close the gridview, open the form
                pnlEdit.Visible = true;
                pnlViewList.Visible = false;
                // load the form for editing
                LoadLineForEditing(gvMyList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```